# FFMPEG: CPU usaged (MP3, AAC, OOG)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm transcoding IPTV to HLS streaming, but getting issue with CPU, my VPS is too weak :D lose 10% CPU if transcode mpga layer 2 to aac. So i'm finding the best audio code that uses lowest CPU. Let's give a suggestion

AAC/MP3/OOG

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per *RFC 8216 - HTTP Live Streaming* `ogg` is not supported. Only `aac`, `ac3`, `eac3` and `mp3` are accepted.

One thing to keep in mind if you ever need to publish to Apple's App Store is that there's no mention of `mp3` whatsoever in their latest HLS recommendation and they specifically require stereo in `aac`.

This leaves you with `aac`, get a better VPS.

Comment: Im using HLS.JS. So I think mp3 is not a problem . What i need is CPU :D aac or mp3?

Comment: @beeb.vn benchmark. On my machine `lame` uses more than `fdkaac`.

Comment: I dont know when I try, I see that lame uses less CPU than aac :D

Comment: @beeb.vn that's why it's important to benchmark :) Try the Fraunhofer FDK AAC encoder if you haven't already (`libfdk_aac`).